# Gnus only fetch latest X emails?

Tags: gnus

I'm using Gnus for the first time with gmail.

I have a lot of emails which I've read but just don't delete, 20k or so.

I want to access them more like the web browser that is only the newest 100 or so.

How can I do this?

My `~/.authinfo`:

```
machine imap.gmail.com login kirkins@gmail.com port imaps
machine smtp.gmail.com login kirkins@gmail.com  port 587
```

Comment: You're using imap, correct?  If so, could you edit that info into the post, please?

Comment: @Dan I added my `~./authinfo` that's the only thing I set up to get it working.

Comment: You may find the [documentation for selecting groups](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Selecting-a-Group.html) useful. In particular, see how prefix arguments affect `SPC` and `RET`. IIRC Gnus usually asks how many articles to fetch in any case.